# Unable to calculate discount

Tags: java, arrays

Hey everyone so I'm new to programming and recently I've been introduced to array's I've been having some problems in my current project. Essentially I am getting an array out of bounds exception when trying to calculate the discount price (afterDiscount located at the bottom) however when I run the program I get this error. I'm not sure how to fix it as I have not dealt with arrays before.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
        at StarterJ52PartPriceDiscount.main(StarterJ52PartPriceDiscount.java:108)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StarterJ52PartPriceDiscount
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // Constants
        final int MAX = 30; // max records on parts.dat
        final int SENTINEL = 999;
        // File Objects - Parts and Trans files
        Scanner inPartsFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("parts.dat"));
        Scanner inTransFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("trans.dat"));

        // Part file Variables
        int stkPartNo;
        double stkPartPrice; // ???

        // Tx file Variables
        int txPartNo;
        int txQuantity;
        int txDiscountCode;

        // Arrays
        int[] partNos = new int[MAX];
        double[] prices = new double[MAX];
        int[] discounts = {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50}; // Discount Percentages

        // Other Variables
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int recCount;                               // no records on file
        int cnt, foundPosition,i,pos;                       // index
        double beforeDiscount, afterDiscount, totalDiscount, cost;
        boolean found;

        // Initialise
        recCount = 0;
        foundPosition = 0;
        totalDiscount = 0;
        found = false;
        pos =-1;
        // Output Part No and Prices (for)
        System.out.println("Part No Part Price");
        for(i=0; i <MAX; i++)
        {

            stkPartNo = inPartsFile.nextInt();
            stkPartPrice = inPartsFile.nextDouble();
            //System.out.printf("%2d %4.2f %n",stkPartNo,stkPartPrice );

            partNos[i] = stkPartNo;
            prices[i] = stkPartPrice;
            System.out.printf("%6d  %7.2f  %n",partNos[i],prices[i]);


        }//for


        // Initial Tx read of first record
        txPartNo=inTransFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Part Quantity Disc Code");
        while(txPartNo != SENTINEL)
        {

             txQuantity = inTransFile.nextInt();
             txDiscountCode = inTransFile.nextInt();

             System.out.printf("%4d %4d %4d %n",txPartNo,txQuantity,txDiscountCode );

            txPartNo=inTransFile.nextInt();
        }//While
            // Verify Tx trans.dat contents (initially)
        inTransFile.close();
        inTransFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("trans.dat"));

        System.out.println("xxxxxxx");

        txPartNo=inTransFile.nextInt();//initial Read

        while(txPartNo != SENTINEL)
        {

            txQuantity = inTransFile.nextInt();
            txDiscountCode = inTransFile.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%4d %4d ",txPartNo,txQuantity );

            found = false;
            pos = -1;

            while (pos < partNos.length -1 && found == false)
            {
                ++pos;

                if (partNos[pos] == txPartNo){
                    found = true;
                }
                else if (partNos[pos] > txPartNo){ // Ordered
                    pos = partNos.length; // break;
                }
            } // inner while

            if (found) { // == true
                beforeDiscount =  prices[pos];

                //Throws out of bounds exeption
                afterDiscount = beforeDiscount - (beforeDiscount * discounts[txDiscountCode]);

                System.out.printf("%4.2f %n",beforeDiscount);
                System.out.printf("%4.2f %n",afterDiscount);




            }
            else {
                System.out.println("NOT Found");
            }//if


            txPartNo=inTransFile.nextInt();//Sub Read

        }//While




    }  // main

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] (maybe adding a very short version of the files you are using to the post)?

Comment: Your code tries to access `discounts[9]`. However, the `discounts` array has only 9 elements, namely `discounts[0]` to `discounts[8]`. You always have to start counting from 0 instead of 1. Maybe this is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThankYou for your comments I was able to rectify the problem, my discount array was beginning at position 1 rather than position 2, therefore, cause the out of bounds exception

changed the code from this

```
afterDiscount = beforeDiscount - (beforeDiscount * discounts[txDiscountCode]);
```

to this

```
afterDiscount = beforeDiscount - (beforeDiscount * discounts[txDiscountCode-1]);
```